# Locate a record in a TDBAdvGrid with PageMode off

Tags: delphi, tms

I am desperately trying to do a Locate on a record whose PK is associated to Column 0 in a TDBAdvGrid. The TMS Component Pack version I have is 6.8.something.
I am using it in a Win7x64 with Delphi XE 1.
PageMode is turned off because I will need sorting and grouping at the client level(no backend db for now, only client datasets in offline mode).

My code for the locate is like this:

```
procedure TMainFrm.EditAction;
var ItemID : Integer;
    ItemIDStr: String;
begin
  // With PageMode set to false(which we need), the dataset is not synchronized.
  //ItemID := GetActionGrid.Columns[ 0 ].Field.AsInteger;
  ItemIDStr := GetActionGrid.Cells[ 0,GetActionGrid.SelectedRow[ 0 ] ];
  ItemID := StrToIntDef( ItemIDStr ,-1 );
//  GetActionGrid.Fields[ 0 ].AsInteger;
  If DMMain.CLNActions.Locate( 'ITEM_ID',ItemID,[] ) Then
    CreateApplicationForm( TActionFrm, True );
end;
```

But it does not work because the ItemIDStr always returns an empty string.
I am really short of ideas now.

Suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: It is interesting, I have created a calculated field which converts the ITEM_ID in a string, and a code very similar to that(apart from col 0) does work with that trick. The problem is that at that point the ITEM_ID becomes visible(something I don't want) and there seems to be no way to hide it.

Comment: Another thing I tried was to retrive the Int value using the Ints property of Column 0(=zero).
That does not work either.
I really don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function TFrameDBGrid1.GrFindValInCol(FldName, FldVal : String) : boolean; //search value in a certain column of the grid
var
   StartCell:TPoint;
   FindParams: TFindParams;
   rv:TPoint;
   CurrCol: integer;
  I: Integer;
const CResultInvalidInt=-1;
begin
  Result := false;
  StartCell.x := CResultInvalidInt;
  StartCell.y := CResultInvalidInt;
  CurrCol := GetColumnIndexOfField(FldName);
  grdGlobal.FindCol := CurrCol;
  FindParams := [fnMatchRegular, fnFindInPresetCol];
  rv:=grdGlobal.Find(StartCell, FldVal, FindParams);
  Result:= (rv.x <> CResultInvalidInt) and (rv.y <> CResultInvalidInt);
  if Result then
    if grdGlobal.Row <> rv.y then
      grdGlobal.Row := rv.y;
end;
```

Comment: Please add a few lines of explanation to help grasp the gist of your answer.

Comment: Indeed, I will try that when I get home(why doesn't stack overflow notify you of answers?).